# SVG градиент на внутренних страницах и тег BASE

Tags: html, вёрстка, svg, safari, svg-спрайт

Есть `svg` градиент, который применяется на всех страницах сайта:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="0" height="0" style="position: absolute;" xml:base="">
<defs>
    <radialgradient cx="19.111" cy="128.444" gradientunits="userSpaceOnUse" id="instagram-gradient" r="163.552">
        <stop offset="0" stop-color="#ffb140"/><stop offset=".256" stop-color="#ff5445"/>
        <stop offset=".599" stop-color="#fc2b82"/><stop offset="1" stop-color="#8e40b7"/>
   </radialgradient>
</defs>
```

далее его применяю на `USE`

```
<svg><use xlink:href="#sprite-in" fill="url(#instagram-gradient)"/></svg>
```

Но если на странице присутствует тег `<base>` то градиент работает только на главной странице. На внутренних градиент теряется.

Эта проблема наблюдается в Safari (десктоп/мобайл), в хроме все ок.

Сталкивался кто нибудь с таким?

Comment: `xml:base=""` - это я уже пробовал решить проблему, но не помогло..

Answer (score 4):

Одной из причин отказа работоспособности градиента может быть:

- У вас для градиента значения указаны `stop offset=".599"` в долях от
  единицы, поэтому `gradientunits` должен иметь значение -
  `gradientunits= "objectBoundingBox"` или не указывать, так как это
  значение по умолчанию.
- Для кроссбраузерности лучше добавлять градиент в каждый фрагмент svg
  кода, который вы окрашиваете.

Попробуйте добавить фрагмент кода с градиентом через `<object>`

`<object type="image/svg+xml" data="images/svgdefs.svg">
      Your  browser does not support SVG 
    </object>`

- Далее вызываете градиент по `ID`

  `<svg class="inline-svg-icon"> 
  <use  xlink:href="svgdefs.svg#instagram-gradient"></use> 
  </svg>`